# pythonic way to create python lists of runtime length

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, styles

The `f=[]` in the below code seems a waste of a line, but I don't know how to get around it.

1)

```
f=[]
for x in X:
   f.append(foo(x))
```

2)

```
f=[]
[f.append(foo(x)) for x in X]
```

I was just wondering what the most "pythonic" way to do this is. The `f=[]` line seems unpythonic.

Answer (score 3):

You better read about [list comprehensions in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
f = [foo(x) for x in X]
```

Comment: Thank you. What if instead of foo, it is several lines of y=foo1(x), z=foo2(y) f.append(z)? I guess I would have to make new function to do foo1 then foo2 or else cram it into one line with [foo4(foo3(...foo1(x))) for x in X]?

Comment: well, it depends :-) Both solutions you provided are ok. Which is better - depends on concrete situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = [None]*len(X)
```

creates a list of None elements in the same size as X, and is O(n)

```
f = list(X)
```

copies X to f and has the same time complexity as the above according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

If you meant to specifically create a list where every element is foo(x), then yeah:

```
f = [foo(x) for x in X]
```

Comment: What would be the point of the first option? I don't think you can later say
for y in f:
    y=something_more_interesting

Comment: The only point I can think of is reusing f recursively so you don't need to allocate more memory for each recursion cycle